# Chrome DOM not updating for jQuery append/fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom

After fetching a new record from the server, I use the AJAX success callback from jQuery 1.7.2 to add a new record to the list and fade it in.

```
function onSuccess (data, status, xhr) {
    var record = $(template_html);

    // populate `record` with `data` values.

    body.append(record); // body is a jQuery object from closure scope
    record.fadeIn('fast');
}
```

I tested this in the following browsers:

- IE 8
- IE 9
- Safari 5.1.7
- Firefox 14.0.1
- Chrome 21.0.1180.79
- Opera 11.64

It works in all of the above browsers consistently, except for Chrome. It works occasionally in Chrome.

When it fails in Chrome, if I click "Inspect Element" or view the Elements tab on the Developer Tools, or click on the DOM element that is printed to the Javascript Console using `console.log(record)`, it causes the new record to pop into visibility.

I know that the DOM element is being created, populated, and appended correctly. The problem is that sometimes Chrome refuses to re-render the DOM. Sometimes.

I've tried replacing `fadeIn` with `show` or `fadeTo` with no change.

None of the answers in "Similar Questions" have worked for me. The markup for the record is just `<div>`s in `<div>`s, and I validated the page before and after adding new records to see if invalid HTML might be the issue.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Im not sure about this, but i have to ask: don't you have the overflow hidden css property for the parent div?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var body = document.body;
    $(body).append(function () {
        return $('<div>').addClass('Appended').html('Test Div </br> :)');
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.Appended').fadeIn('fast');

        // i'm used timeout to see the effect
    }, 1500);
});
```

you can check it by this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rasoolghafari/6PFRS/)